# Can C++ const method calls be reordered by optimizer?

Tags: c++, constants, compiler-optimization

[This isocpp.org FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#logical-vs-physical-const) on constness says:

> (...) let’s be precise about whether a method changes the object’s logical state. If you are outside the class — you are a normal user, every experiment you could perform (every method or sequence of methods you call) would have the same results (same return values, same exceptions or lack of exceptions) irrespective of whether you first called that lookup method. If the lookup function changed any future behavior of any future method (not just making it faster but changed the outcome, changed the return value, changed the exception), then the lookup method changed the object’s logical state — it is a mutuator. But if the lookup method changed nothing other than perhaps making some things faster, then it is an inspector.

This *seems* to imply that the compiler is free to assume calls to inspectors can be freely reordered if they don't include writes to volatiles/calls to IO library functions (or maybe even cached and ommitted). Is that the case?

If the answer is no, is there any situation in which constness will allow for some optimization by allowing the compiler to assume something it cannot prove? (it seems proving an object could be const is trivial, but maybe it gets complicated when passing references?)

Comment: See the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). Anything can be changed by the compiler provided it will never change the observable behavior. Note that this is observable behavior as defined by the language. Things like memory usage, cpu time usage and undefined behavior's observable behavior are not required to be preserved since they are not defined by the standard.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, call reordering is probably not going to happen if the `const` method is provided by another TU, since it would not be possible for the compiler to actually prove the `const` method is not doing some IO. And even then I'd be surprised if it did reordering unless inlining that `const` function.

Comment: @Asu Link time optimization (LTO) is able to observe all TU at the same time. gcc, clang, VC all support it.